# Rendering PDF template in django in arabic language

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have a problem with rendering pdf template in arabic words that i made table contains rows of classes (goods) in store  here is the code of Generate pdf

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
template = get_template(template_src)
html  = template.render(context_dict)
result = BytesIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("iso-8859-6")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
return None
```

in encode i put iso-8859-6 i searched for arabic encode and try this and it dos not work plaese any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is likely that your terminal is not able to render the result, so try in your terminal:

```
pip install win_unicode_console
```

Then, in python:

```
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()
```

Then, substitute the below line as before:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("cp1252")), result)
```

Comment: it shows this error

'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1268-1274: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: my os is windows 10

Comment: ok I updated my answer - I think the problem is that your Windows terminal is not able to render the unicode.